# Jquery Dialog - Reuseable on manyimages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the Jquery UI Dialog box to make a popup for images on my page.

Currently for each image, I'm using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myImageInfo").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: "center",
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            title: "Image Title",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#MyImageLink")

          .click(function () {
              $("#MyImageInfo").dialog("open");
          });

    </script>
```

My HTML,

```
<a id="MyImageLink" href="#">
        <img src="blahblahblah.jpg"></a>


    <div id="MyImage" title="Basic modal dialog">
         <p><strong>Title Yah</strong></p>
        <p>
            <strong>Phone</strong>: ****<br />
            <strong>Email</strong>:<a href="mailto:"></a>
            </a>
    </div>
```

My issue is I have about 10 of the pictures set up the same, each with thier uniqu ID's how can I use this script more efficiently so I only have to include it once? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique.But you can apply the same class name to more than one element.

You can give same class name to all those elements.and then use

```
$(".className").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: "center",
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            title: "Image Title",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay You must not put same id multiple elems at same page, ids must have to be unique either postfix some counter values like `MyImageLink1, MyImageLink2, MyImageLink3` or better option is to change `id` to `class` this way:

```
<a class="MyImageLink" href="#"><img src="blahblahblah.jpg"></a>

<div class="MyImage" title="Basic modal dialog">
    .......
</div>
```

#### Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function dialg(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".myImageInfo").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            position: "center",
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            title: "Image Title",
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
   }

    $(function(){
        $(".MyImageLink").on('click', dialg);
    });

    </script>
```